# Cuando selecciono un select, que se autocomplete un campo

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy intentando encontrar la forma de que se autorellene el campo Estado (id=fe696) con la palabra "Reagendado" cuando en el select escojo "reagendar" y que se autorellene el campo Estado con la palabra "Contestado" cuando en el select escojo "contestar".
No me funciona lo que he estado haciendo, dejo más o menos lo que he intentado.
Muchas gracias!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery.datetimepicker2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="prettify-1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="jquery.boostrap-datatimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker2.full.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.boostrap-datatimepicker.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
  <label for="pais">Acción</label>
    <select name="cmb3" id="cmb3" required="required">
        <option value="CONTESTAR" selected>Contestar</option>
         <option value="REAGENDAR">Reagendar</option>
    </select>
   
   <input name="Estado" id="fe696" value="">
</form>



<script>
                           
var select1 = document.getElementById('cmb3');
var select17 = document.getElementById('fe696');



select1.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
    if(select1.selectedIndex == 1) {
      select17.attributes['required'] = Contestado; 
    }else {
      select17.attributes['required'] = Reagendado;
          
    }
  
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cambiar un `input` debes modificar la propiedad `value` de éste. No `required`.

```
input.value = 'Some value';
```

El primer error que te sale es

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Contestado is not defined"

porque `Contestado` y `Reagendado` no son variables, te falta ponerlas entre comillas.

Otro error, los índices de los `select` empiezan por `0`. En tu caso, el índice `0` es "Contestar".

Y, por último, te recomendaría poner un primer valor por defecto al `input` igual que con el `select` para que al principio, cuando no se haya cambiado el `select`, el `input` tenga igualmente el valor `"Contestado"`.

Aquí te dejo con los cambios.

```
<form>
    <label for="pais">Acción</label>
    <select name="cmb3" id="cmb3" required="required">
        <option value="CONTESTAR" selected>Contestar</option>
        <option value="REAGENDAR">Reagendar</option>
    </select>
    
    <input name="Estado" id="fe696" value="Contestado">
</form>

<script>
    const select = document.getElementById('cmb3');
    const input = document.getElementById('fe696');

    select.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
        if(select.selectedIndex === 0)
            select17.value = 'Contestado'; 

        else
            select17.value = 'Reagendado';
    });
</script>
```

Espero que sirva.